# How can I use python to sent POST requests

Tags: python

I am tring to use python to send POST requests

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = input("Please input your choice, only GET and POST: ")
    if c == 'GET':
        webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort_G), GetHandler)
        print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort_G))
        try:
            webServer.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        webServer.server_close()
        print("Server stopped.")
        
    elif c == 'POST':
        webServer_post = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort_P), PostHandler)
        print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort_P))
        try:
            webServer_post.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        webServer_post.server_close()
        print("Server stopped.")
        
    else:
        print('WRONG')
```

And here is the PostHandeler, res_type and post_data

```
class PostHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        flag = 'POST'
        res_type(self, 200, flag)
        #result_output(self, flag)

def res_type(self, num, flag):
    if flag == 'GET':
        self.send_response(num)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
        self.end_headers()
    elif flag == 'POST':
        self.send_response(num)
        self.end_headers()
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(post_data)
    return

def post_data():
    json_data = {
        'operation':'add',
        'arguments':[4,6]
    }
    
    data_headers = {'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accepet':'text/plain'}
    data_payload = json.dumps(json_data)
    
    try:
        post = requests.post('http://localhost:8088/post', data = data_payload, headers = data_headers)
        print(post.status_code)
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
```

But I got this error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 16:04:02] code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 16:04:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 501 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 16:04:03] code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2021 16:04:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

My friend said that the default access approach is send a GET request to a website.
Is there any way to send POST request directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requests.post()` method is the right tool for this task.

But in your log I see a request of `/` + `/favicon.ico`. It means that you tried to reach your webserver with a browser, not with the Python code.

Make sure you are connecting to the right webserver with your Python code.